# Test for performace.now() via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I test if a browser supports performace.now() vs Date().now ?
My mobile browser is throwing an error when it attempts to invoke performace.now().

```
if (performance) {
    performace.now()
}
```

The above does not work.

Comment: `Date().now()` is invalid, Date object instance doesn't have a now method. It should be `Date.now()`. By the way, what is your goal? If it's just a performance measurements while testing algorithms, i.e. it's not going to be viewed by users, you can use [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.time).

Answer (score 1):

Try `if (window.performance) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this validation:

```
if (('performance' in window) && (typeof performance.now === 'function')) {
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Would this be faster than using a try block?

Comment: Yes. Avoid using try block inside performance-critical functions. More information here https://dev.opera.com/articles/efficient-javascript/?page=2#trycatch

Comment: @frosdqy: Notice that feature detection is typically not performance-critical :-)